# How to mock tls.PeerCertificate with Jest using Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am able to mock getCertificate with jasmine like this:

```
const socket = new TLSSocket(new net.Socket())
socket.authorized = false
socket.authorizationError = Error('Invalid certificate')
//Mocking here
const spyOnGetCertificate = spyOn(socket, 'getCertificate').and.returnValue({'subject': {'CN': 'testing'}});
```

However, when I try with jest:

```
const socket = new TLSSocket(new net.Socket())
socket.authorized = false
socket.authorizationError = Error('Invalid certificate')
//Mocking here
const spyOnGetCertificate = jest.spyOn(socket, 'getCertificate').mockImplementationOnce(() => {
  return {'subject': {'CN': 'testing'}}
})
socket.getCertificate = spyOnGetCertificate
```

I get an error:

> Type 'SpyInstance' is not assignable to type '() => object | PeerCertificate'.
>     Type 'SpyInstance' provides no match for the signature '(): object | PeerCertificate'.ts(2322)

I still get the error when I have set all the PeerCertificate properties.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, don't need to do this ‍♂️

```
socket.getCertificate = spyOnGetCertificate
```